# Does Python have any standard lib which can compare two files by omitting the first several lines?

Tags: python

Does Python have any standard lib which can compare two files by omitting the first several lines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong in write your own?

```
def skipNdCmp(f1, f2,skip1,skip2,bufsize = 8*1024):
    with open(f1, 'rb') as fp1, open(f2, 'rb') as fp2:
        for i in xrange(0,skip1): fp1.readline()
        for i in xrange(0,skip2): fp2.readline()
        while True:
                b1 = fp1.read(bufsize)
                b2 = fp2.read(bufsize)
                if b1 != b2:
                    return False
                if not b1:
                    return True
```

Reference filecmp.py

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [filecmp](http://docs.python.org/library/filecmp.html#module-filecmp) and [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#module-difflib). They don't support skipping lines out-of-the-box but that you can implement yourself.